# Why doesn't zero padding with integers work in Matlab formatSpec?

Tags: matlab, printf, format-specifiers

I am trying to pad a number with zeros as follows.

Desired:

```
7 -> '07'
8 -> '08'
```

(In case it matters, the input is intended as a character vector to be converted by `num2str`. But for the examples below, direct numeric input does not seem to be any different.)

```matlab
>> num2str(7,'%02.u')
ans =
    '7'    % does not pad the zeros
>> num2str(7,'%02.f')
ans =
    '07'   % works as intended
```

Why doesn't `'%02.u'` work?

Comment: `num2str(7,'%02u')` works in Octave.

Comment: I can't see it documented other than `u` being an `int` format, which I guess is interpreted as needing to "look" like an integer which would not contain leading zeros. `'u'` gives the same behaviour as `'d'` (the signed `'int'` format)

Comment: Is your question only "why doesn't it work?" or "how to do this?"

Comment: @beaker, it works in MATLAB too. This is just a syntax error. The `.` is only used for the floating point number formats (`%f`, `%g`, `%e`, ...), not for the integral type (`%u`, `%d`, `%o`, `%i`, `%x`, ...). Obviously, it wouldn't make sense either for the ASCII types (`%c`, `%s`).

Comment: @Hoki although the case for using the precision specifier for `%s` is at least [documented](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z8vc-3): _While you can specify the precision in a formatting operator for input text (for example, in the %s operator), there is usually no reason to do so. If you specify the precision as p, and p is less than the number of characters in the input text, then the output contains only the first p characters._ Whereas I can't see the `%u` behaviour documented

Comment: I see. I thought precision should/could still be entered but would be ignored for `%u` format. That answers my question. The intent of the question is on the why part -- I wanted to understand format spec better. Thanks, all.